# OSGi: Could not resolve javax.servlet

Tags: java, osgi, osgi-bundle, equinox

I have a server side OSGi application, running in an equinox container. This application uses the `org.apache.felix.webconsole (4.6.2)` and other bundles. These other bundles need *javax.http > 4.0.0* which I provide with the `jakarta.servlet-api (4.0.0)`. `org.apache.felix.webconsole` needs *javax.servlet=[2.4.0,4.0.0)* which I provide with the bundle `javax.servlet-api (3.1.0)`.

When I start the application, the OSGi runtime complains with the a *BundleException*:
`Could not resolve module: org.apache.felix.webconsole / Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: javax.servlet; version="[2.4.0,4.0.0)"`

What can I do to fix this problem?

Comment: Please check that you actually have servlet-api 3 and 4 bundles installed. It looks like the version 3 is missing.
Other than that be aware that usually you not only want an api but also an implementation. In many cases in OSGi the bundle that provides the implementation also provides the api. 
Also check the Manifest of the api bundles. In OSGi the important part is not the bundle version but rather that package exports in the Manifest.

Comment: I guess, the hint concerning the difference between api and implementation is correct. After adding a bundle that provides the implementation, the error message went away.

Answer (score 0):

From the Error I can get to know, OGSI Expects javax-servlet version  greater than 2.4.0
So you can check with this dependency in your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
 </dependency>
```

Comment: I'm using pomless build with Tycho, so this is not a solution in my case.